# I have trouble choosing puppeteer css selector

Tags: javascript, html, css, puppeteer

i need puppetter page.type css select.

```
<div class="preloader">
  <div class="cssload-speeding-wheel"></div>
</div>
<section id="wrapper" class="login-register">
  <div class="login-box">
      <div class="white-box">
      <form class="form-horizontal form-material" id="loginform" method="post">
        <h3 class="box-title m-b-20">Sign In</h3>
        <div class="form-group ">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" required="" name="login-username" placeholder="Username">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input class="form-control" type="password" required="" name="login-password"  placeholder="Password">
          </div>
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-md-12">

        </div>
        <div class="form-group text-center m-t-20">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <button type="submit" name="doLogin" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block text-uppercase waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">Log In</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group m-b-0">
```

i need username,password and dologin.

page.type("input[@placeholder='Username']", 'MYUSERNAME');

This code not working.. pls help me

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for the `@` in your selector and placeholder is a pseudo element. You could use another attribute for your selector:

```
page.type("input[name='login-username']", 'MYUSERNAME');
```

Although I'd suggest giving your elements IDs as this will give better selector performance:

```
<input id="username" class="form-control" type="text" required="" name="login-username" placeholder="Username">
```

and then

```
page.type('#username', 'MYUSERNAME');
```

Comment: (node:1677) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No node found for selector: input[placeholder='Username']

not found ?

Comment: apologies, `placeholder` is a pseudo element - try either adding an id as I suggested, or use another attribute, e.g. `page.type("input[name='login-username']", 'MYUSERNAME');` - answer updated

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be helpful for you for solving your problem.I have tried to make it more simple understandable.So that you can be able to clarify your concept.

```
  /**
 * seperate your field information
 * 
 */
let loginAccount ={
    username:"input[name='login-username']",
    password:"input[name='login-password']",
    loginSubmit:".btn"
}
 /**  Enter username */
 await page.waitForSelector(loginAccount.username);
 await page.click(loginAccount.username);
 await page.keyboard.type('krdheeraj51');
 /** Similiarly for login password */
 await page.waitForSelector(loginAccount.password);
 await page.click(loginAccount.password);
 await page.keyboard.type('enter your password');
 /** click your submit button */
 await page.waitFor(2000);
 await page.waitForSelector(loginAccount.loginSubmit);
 await page.click(loginAccount.loginSubmit);
```